# recursively generate stills from video within nested directories using zsh and ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, terminal, zsh

The following command performs what I need to if all mp4s are in the same directory:

`for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps=0.5 "$i-%d.jpg"; done`

**E.g.**

1.mp4
2.mp4

However my these are now within folders with in the same directory, for example:

```
dir1/1.mp4
dir2/2.mp4
```

How can I modify this command to go recursively enter each directory and perform the `ffmpeg` on each video it finds within the folder?

The end result should be:

```
dir1
    1.mp4
    1-1.jpg
    1-2.jpg
    1-3.jpg

dir2
    2.mp4
    2-1.jpg
    2-2.jpg
    2-3.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh` you can match directories recursively with the `**` glob, provided the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option is enabled. You can enable options with the `setopt` builtin (e.g. in your `~/.zshrc`):

```
setopt extendedglob
```

The `**` glob matches zero or more directories. So `**/*.mp4` would match `dir1/1.mp4` and `dir2/2.mp4` in your example. Assuming that ffmpeg allows full paths in both parameters where you use `$i`, nothing else needs to be changed:

```
for i in **/*.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps=0.5 "$i-%d.jpg"; done
```

Starting with `zsh` 5.2 you can also additionally set the `GLOB_STAR_SHORT`, which allows you to shorten `**/*.mp4` to `**.mp4`.

```
for i in **.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps=0.5 "$i-%d.jpg"; done
```